# What are the Rate codes to monitor for AmazonEC2 service while installing Datadog AWS Pricing integration?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, datadog, aws-devops

I have created a test aws ec2 instance (amazon-linux) in us-east-1 region and installed datadog-agent in it and installed aws pricing integration to get pricing metrics as in this [documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/aws_pricing/) to datadog agent and the following error occurs.

`Datadog’s aws_pricing integration is reporting: •   Instance #aws_pricing:d884b5186b651429[ERROR]: [{"message": "No rate codes for existing AWS services were defined, please fix conf.yaml", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py\", line 1120, in run\n self.check(instance)\n File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/aws_pricing/aws_pricing.py\", line 29, in check\n raise CheckException(message)\ndatadog_checks.base.errors.CheckException: No rate codes for existing AWS services were defined, please fix conf.yaml\n"}] •   Instance #aws_pricing:698d047c39b859c1[ERROR]: [{"message": "No rate codes for existing AWS services were defined, please fix conf.yaml", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py\", line 1120, in run\n self.check(instance)\n File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/aws_pricing/aws_pricing.py\", line 29, in check\n raise CheckException(message)\ndatadog_checks.base.errors.CheckException: No rate codes for existing AWS services were defined, please fix conf.yaml\n"}]`

it seems like I have to edit the following conf file which located in ( /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/aws_pricing.d/conf.yaml ) datadog configuration in my ec2 server.

```
`
init_config:
instances:
  -
    ## @param region_name - string - optional - default: us-east-1
    ## AWS region to run PricingService requests in.
    ## As of writing, only us-east-1 and ap-south-1 are supported.
    ## See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/using-pelong.html
    #
    # - region_name: us-east-1

    ## Below is an example of how you would configure monitoring for AmazonEC2 pricing.
    ## This same format can be used for any other AWS service.

    ## @param AmazonEC2 - list - optional
    ## Rate codes to monitor for AmazonEC2 service.
    #
    # - AmazonEC2:
    #   - <RATE_CODE_1>
    #   - <RATE_CODE_2>
    #   - <RATE_CODE_3>
`
```

You can find this example code [here](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-extras/blob/master/aws_pricing/datadog_checks/aws_pricing/data/conf.yaml.example).

I want to find out the specific RATE_CODES under the amazonec2 in this file. ( for RATE_CODE_1, RATE_CODE_2,RATE_CODE_3 etc).By installing this one I'm expecting to get the aws.pricing.amazonec2 metric to show the cost of amazon ec2 per unit. I'm creating a datadog dashboard regarding this.

datadog support has shared these example resources to refer,

1. explanation around what rate_code is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/reading-an-offer.html#offer-term-rate-codes)
2. [example of a rate code](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-price-list-api-update-new-query-and-metadata-functions/)

look for the following code snippet

```
`
"rateCode": {     
                 "rateCode":"The rate code of the price", 
                 "description":"The description of the term", 
                 "unit":"The usage measurement unit for the price", 
                 "startingRange":"The start range for the term", 
                 "endingRange":"The end range for the term", 
                 "pricePerUnit": {       
                    "currencyCode":"currencyRate", 
                 }            
`
```

If you find out the solution it's great if you can share the configured conf.yaml code with me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [follow the instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-price-list-api-update-new-query-and-metadata-functions/) to get the rate codes yourself based on what kind of EC2 instances you are using. Nobody else will be able to provide this for you; it depends on things like instance size, region, reserved/on-demand, etc. You might also want to look at the [API documentation for the price list API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/using-pelong.html), and especially consider using the SDK for whatever language you are working in.